# Record related options are not present in Builder of community

Tags: community, customer-community, community-builder

I am trying to show record detail page on community. I clicked on new page and selected object page which added things like detail page, related list in page option. I cant see any record related options in component list of Builder in my community. Whereas its visible in other's community builder in blogs, youtube videos. Please help Am I missing anything? The end goal is displaying record on community.
[image]

Comment: Have you added the related record definitions in the page layouts?

Comment: I am not able to see any record option to drag and drop and set related information

Comment: I mean in the page layouts, not in the community builder.

Comment: What object did you choose- Standard/ Custom? What is your experience site's template?

Comment: custom object and build your own community template